# Find top records in a tree given a set of nodes

Tags: algorithm

For a tree like this, I'd like to choose from a given list of nodes only top nodes discarding those that are already contained in a parent node. Example Tree

- World

  - Americas

    - North America

      - Usa

        - Alabama
        - New-York *

          - Brooklyn
          - Queens *
      - Canada *
  - Europe *

    - Germany
    - Italy *
    - France

      - Paris *

Given this list: New-York, Queens, Canada, Europe, Italy, Paris

The espected output is: New-York, Canada, Europe.

(Queens is discarded because is in New-York, Italy is discarded because is in Europe, Paris is discarded because is also in Europe, etc)

My tree is physicaly in an oracle table tree with records id, parent_id

What is the optimal algorithm to apply in this scenario? Avoiding unnecesary calls to DB.

Comment: Since you have no way to know, where the given nodes are in your tree, you will traverse the whole tree in worst case.

Comment: I think [this](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2129244/hierarchy-query-for-full-tree) is very relevant for your question

Comment: How many records do you have in your table, and what is the height of the tree? Will the logic be on the database server (all in SQL?) or do you have the array elsewhere? If you want to minimize the **calls** from the application to the database, then obviously you could make one call that fetches the whole tree. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of values in the list is relatively small to the number of the values in the table, then you might start from the records that correspond to the list values, and walk upwards in the tree until you either reach the root or reach another value in the list. Only retain those results where the upward search stops at the root.

I'll assume that the `id` and `parent_id` fields are the names of the countries (alternatively they could be unique numbers, with the name of the country in a third field). I'll also assume that there is a record with `id` equal to `'World'` and a corresponding `parent_id` that is `NULL`.

Then you could do this with a single SQL query on the Oracle database:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM (
  SELECT     CONNECT_BY_ROOT id id,
             parent_id
  FROM       tbl
  START WITH id IN ('New-York', 'Queens', 'Canada', 'Europe', 'Italy', 'Paris')
  CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = id 
         AND id NOT IN ('New-York', 'Queens', 'Canada', 'Europe', 'Italy', 'Paris')
) 
WHERE parent_id IS NULL;
```

The list appears twice in the query, once to denote at which records to start, and once to indicate when the upward traversal should abort.

The final `WHERE` clause ensures that the paths from lists reached the root, and did not abort at another value in the list.

The above query returns this result for the tree you depicted:

```
Canada
Europe
Queens
```

See it run on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/146af5/2)

Comment: Thanks @trincot. You simply hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the worst case is that you have to traverse the whole tree, if for instance none of your search targets are in the tree, or they happen to be the last N leaves you visit.

So, any tree traversal algorithm should work, provided that as soon as you find one of your target values, you stop searching the subtree rooted at that node. That will avoid unnecessary searching of a subtree that cannot have any other top-level items than the root. In your example, the traversal might look like this:

World, North Americas, USA, Alabama, New York (this is a match; return and go back up the tree until there is an unvisited child somewhere), Canada (this is a match; return and go back up the tree until there is an unvisited child somewhere), Europe (this is a match; return and go back up the tree until there is an unvisited child somewhere).